# False "Generate Signed APK - APK(s) generated successfully" message pop-up every time I do a build (after generating a signed apk once)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, apk, signing

This is happening across all projects for me. When I generate a signed apk from Android Studio I get the following message which is correct:

[image]

**Problem:** After this I continue getting this message for every build that happens for the project, when I'm not actually generating a signed apk.

I checked the destination folder to see if the apk is actually getting generated but it is not. Then why do I get the message? After restarting Android Studio it stops.

Is this a misconfiguration in the project or settings or is it a bug in Android Studio? I'm using `Android Studio 1.5.1`

**Update:** I do not wish to disable `lint` and suppress the issue. I'm actually looking for a real fix (probably a `configuration or settings change` in the `IDE` or `gradle` files)

---

As mentioned in the answer I accepted, by user2082415, **this is a bug in Android Studio**. I'm following the bug report now and will update this post with a solution when available.

Here is the link for the [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=193788)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a similar problem with the "Build APK APK(s) generated successfully." message.
You can find a bugreport concerning this issue behind the following link.
The more people vote for this issue, the soner it will get fixed.

[Link to Bug Report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=193788)

Comment: Link is broken - this is the correct one: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=193788

Answer (score 1):

here is what you can do while building the app moniter the event log this problem might be of the android lint.Due to lint errors the app is not built.Solve those issues or if you want to by pass the lint you will have to write the following in your build.gradle file

```
android {
    ...
    ....
    ...
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        //abortOnError false
    }
}
```

Comment: This may suppress the message but not actually fix it. I do not want to disable lint for the project. I like the checks it does for me. But thanks for the answer! I can use it as a temp way to disable sometimes when the message is really annoying me by blocking the code I'm working on.

Comment: yes in order to release the app  you will have to solve all lint errors but if you want to bypass it you can use it